# Someone commented this on my soccer video: "Trent all the way" I don't know what is that means

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is meant by "someone all the way" like

> Trent all the way!
>   Salah on the way!
>   Vandjk all the way!

Comment: Could you put the comment you're asking about between " marks? Now I don't know where your question ends and the quote starts.

Comment: "Trent all the way!" That what I am asking

Comment: Alright. I suggested some edits to the question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

**[all the way](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20the%20way)**

> : to the full or entire extent : as far as possible
>   *ran all the way home*
>   *seated all the way in the back*

A more literal use in a sports cheer could mean that the player was in action from one side of the court or field "all the way" to the other side. If a player named Trent took possession of the ball from defence and brought it to offence and scores a point. Then one could cheer **"Trent all the way!"**

It is also commonly used with someone's or something's name to mean "full support".
**"Trent all the way!"** then means **"I fully support Trent!"**.

Another way it is used as a cheer is to say that you support them going "all the way to success", whatever ultimate success could be in their field. So you could shout a team name such as:
**"Bears all the way!"** meaning **"I want the Bears to win the championship!"** probably because something good happened that was a step on the way to success.